# Angular 2: How to unit test tabs component with tightly coupled parent and child components

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I followed along [Thoughtram's article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/04/09/developing-a-tabs-component-in-angular-2.html) to create a tab component.

It basically creates two components: `Tab` and `Tabs`. Here `Tabs` component is the parent/host of `Tab` component to group all tabs together. I need to be able to unit test both the components.

The test scenarios that comes to my mind are:

- `Tab` must inject the parent component that it depends on: `Tabs`
- The first tab must be selected by default.
- function `addTab` of `Tabs` must be called once from `Tab` component
- function `selectTab` must be called on click of corresponding tab and the function in turn should set the tab to be active and all other tabs to inactive state.
- and there can be a few more I suppose...

Problem is that I don't know how to test these things and what should be a good approach to do it. I have been though the angular docs but I couldn't get my head around for this scenario. Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 2):

Unit Testing has it already in the name. You want to test only a single unit. Your `Tab` Component should be tested seperately. It has no real dependency to your `Tabs` Component.

So a test could look something like this:

```
@Component({
    template: `<tab tabTitle="tabTitle">{{ content }}</tab>`
})
class TestHostComponent {
     @ViewChild(TabComponent) tab: TabComponent;
     content: string = '';
     tabTitle: string = 'foo';
}

describe('TabComponent', function () {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestHostComponent>;
    let comp: TestHostComponent;
    let debugElement: DebugElement;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ TestHostComponent ]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestHostComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;
        debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
        fixture.detectChanges();    // ngOnInit
    });

    it('should create the component', () => expect(comp).toBeDefined() );

    it('should change the title', () => {
        expect(comp.tab.tabTitle).toBe('foobar');
        comp.tabTitle = 'bar';
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(comp.tab.tabTitle).toBe('bar');
    });

    it('should change the content', () => {
        comp.content = 'foobar';
        fixture.detectChanges();
        let tabTextContent: string = debugElement.query(By.css('tab')).nativeElement.textContent;
        expect(tabTextContent).toBe('foobar');
    });
});
```

Of course, if you really want to test both at the same time, you do it in a similar way, just change the template of your TestHost to something like

```
@Component({
     template: `<tabs><tab tabTitle="tabTitle">{{ content }}</tab></tabs>`
});
```

and adjust your `ViewChilds` and the way you handle `ngOnInit` and `AfterViewInit`.

But as i said, this is not recommended (you could do that in your `TabsComponent` Test to check if your `Tabs` are working correctly if they have one or more `TabComponents` inside, but not in your `TabComponent`).

Just because it makes testing harder and more specific (you have to be in control of angulars lifecycle hooks and such), the size of each of your test collections are getting confusing (which is bad because you have to change stuff most of the time you make changes to your component) and since it's a standalone Component you could run in the scenario that you want to include it somewhere else anyway and have to cover this too.

Hope i could help you.

Comment: Hey! That made things very much clearer. Heaps of thanks :)

Comment: Hey @lexith, isn't it so that tests like `'should change the title'` is like testing if the input binding works? That sort of testing must have already been done by the Angular guys. Should we be testing something better, something else?

Comment: Absolutely, this was just an example. You want to test your own function of course, but there might be usecases where you want to do something like this (for example if the input should get manipulated on change or something...). Again, just an example :)